# Firebase Cloud Messaging not finding User_Properties

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I already setup my user-properties through my code, I can see them in the Analytics screen as below:

[image]

Added them to User-Properties under Custom Definitions.
But when trying to send a push notification, the console shows 0 eligible users as the image below displays:

[image]